# Embedding new work item web form in a custom page

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem, workitem

Is there a way to host the new work item web form for Visual Studio Team Services and TFS 2017 ([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/new-work-item-experience?view=vsts)) within a custom page that my application has? Basically I'd like the users to use my custom web page to create new work items in TFS or Visual Studio Team Services as I do certain pre and post processing on work item that is created using my application. For this I would need to

1. Somehow host the web form on my own page
2. Hook into pre and post save events (if any) of the web form to do the pre and post processing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can embed the new work item form directly within a custom page as the work item form is based on the TFS process and wit definitions.

I can think of is that you can try to write your own extension and call the REST API to create the work item in the custom web page. See [Create your first extension - Call a REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/get-started/visual-studio?view=vsts#rest)

Comment: No I haven't been able to resolve this issue yet. This has slipped down the priority for now but I intend on taking this up sometime next year. I will update this thread as and when I am able to resolve it.